# Spring MVC Hello World application not working

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm trying to write a simple web app to get started with Spring.

Here's what I have:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"> 
    <display-name>HatifimWeb</display-name> 
    <welcome-file-list> 
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list> 
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

main-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="springapp.controller" /> 
    <bean id="viewResolver" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="viewClass" 
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

LoginController.java

```
package springapp.controller; 

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 

@Controller 
public class LoginController { 

    @RequestMapping("/Login") 
    public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception { 
        System.out.println("Login..."); 

        return new ModelAndView("Login", "message", "test"); 
    } 

}
```

index.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<title>Insert title here</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    Hello. 
    <br /> 
    <a href="Login">login</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<title>poopidipoo</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    ${message} 
</body> 
</html>
```

The index.jsp starts well, but when I click to navigate to the login page, I get 404.
I'm using Tomcat 7. And I'm out of ideas, it looks like the DispatcherServlet is not being invoked for some reason.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <a href="Login">login</a> Change this to <a href="/HatifimWeb/Login">login</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue could be that you are missing the context path in your page, try this way:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login">login</a>
```

**Update:**

Can you please also add
`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your `main-servlet.xml`

Comment: Okay, can you directly access the Login from the browser and see what you get `http://localhost:port/contextpath/Login` replace the contextpath with one relevant to you

Comment: I still get the 404. The only way I don't get a 404, is when I put the jsps folder under WebContent and change the href to jsps/Login.jsp. But that's kind of ridiculous since the Controller class isn't being accessed anyway, and main-servlet.xml is supposed to add the prefix and suffix. So I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I have added an update, can you try this also - adding <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: I have put a temporary project in my github location - `https://github.com/bijukunjummen/HatifimWeb.git` with exactly your configuration and it works cleanly - can you pull it from there and try it. Just run `mvn tomcat:run` and access the index at `http://localhost:8080/HatifimWeb/index`

Comment: It works, thanks. But I don't understand why it would not work on eclipse. I tried to find the differences and it occurred to me that the web.xml in my project is under WebContent and not under WEB-INF, then I moved it under WEB-INF and I got an exception saying it couldn't find the DispatcherServlet class.