# Spring 3 MVC - View not being resolved

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

this question is following  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915715/spring-mvc-hello-world-application-not-working).
This is the new web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>HatifimWeb</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is the new index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello.
    <br />
    <a href="Login.do">login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything else is more or less the same.

Now when I try to access Login.do, it enters the correct method in the LoginController, but then I get a 404. It seems the ViewResolver is not doing its job, but I don't know.

What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Hello World application not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915715/spring-mvc-hello-world-application-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about your servlet-context.xml ? You need to have viewResolver inside your servlet context xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in vew

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
              <property name="definitions">
                     <list>    
                        <value>/WEB-INF/definitions.xml</value>
                    </list>
           </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's you and your code.  ViewResolver has been part of Spring since version 1.0, and I can assure you that it works.

You need something like this in your Spring application context XML:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

You can also use annotations, like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/).

Comment: I know it works. I meant it doesn't work for some reason in my application. I have this bean definition in my main-servlet.xml as I posted in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915715/spring-mvc-hello-world-application-not-working